# What is the mathematical term for a shape that fits in a specific coordinates (e.g. a rectangle in cartesian)?

Tags: general-topology, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry, curvilinear-coordinates

Curvilinear orthogonal coordinates systems are important for field analysis; since they facilitate the equation formulation. For example Laplace equation can be formulated in cartesian coordinates system for rectangles or in polar coordinates for wedges.

**My question**:

Is there a specific mathematical term for such shapes whose boundaries fit in a curvilinear orthogonal grid? My guess is that it might be "conformal topology", but I am not sure.

Comment: I do not think there is a special terminology for this. You can call it a "conformal rectangle."